# two router-outlet linked to different routing files

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I'm trying to include a "particular" router-outlet in a component.

this is app.component.html:

```
<div fxFlexFill fxLayout="column">
   <header fxFlex="40px">
       <router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
   </header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

each one is for one different routing file, first one go to header.routing.ts and the second one to app.routing.ts.

Is it possible to do? How can I link any router with its file?

Comment: why not just use 1 routing file?

Comment: but I have components for the content and for the header, how can I use it together?

Comment: you can specify the outlet of the route so it will only appear in the `header` outlet

Comment: so, it's not possible to do, create a header module with its components to show depending on route?

Comment: yes, it is, but you still need to specify the outlet within the routing definition

Comment: and how can I do it?¿

Comment: as previously mentioned a couple of times, by specifying the `outlet` wothing the routing definition for the path

Comment: you mean something like this.router.navigate([{outlets: { popup: ['messages']}}]); that's not what I mean. I want link outler and files

Comment: no, i mean `{path: "test", component: TestComponent, outlet: "header"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible,you can use, outlet feature provided by angular, below is a pseudo example

```
<main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3">
     <div class="col-12">
       <router-outlet name="left"></router-outlet>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3">
     <div class="col-12 sm-12 md-12 xs-12 lg-12">
       <router-outlet name="right"></router-outlet>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</main>
```

and in routes file -

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '', redirectTo: 'processi', pathMatch: 'full',
  children: [
       { path: '', component: TeamDashboardComponent, outlet: 'left' },
       { path: '', component: ChatroomComponent, outlet: 'right' }
    ]
},
. . .
. . . .
. . . . .
}]
```

if you have any doubt in it then please let me know..

Comment: can I use lazyloading, I mean for outlet, path: '', loadChildren: "module", outlet:'left somehow?

Comment: yes, why not, there is no problem in using lazy loading with multiple router-outlet.